# Android Studio: Visiting Local WiFi Links in background

Tags: android, android-studio, web

I'm trying to write an app that connects to an IP-Adresses from an ESP8266 in my WiFi (example: 192.168.2.138). Code on the ESP will be activated if anyone in my WiFi just visits the IP with anything after the IP/ (example: 192.168.2.138/red to make a light red). The app should activate the ESP but not visibly open a browser.

So now my Question: Is it possible to connect to a website in the background? And if yes, how?

Thanks for any help. :)